# Python game logic: "coins" variable is not incrementing

Tags: python, grid, currency

I am working on a game where the player is in search of treasure. Everything works perfectly, although my money system does not work. I need my code to work so that if the user lands on a treasure chest, they gain 10 extra coins. However, their number of coins is being set to 10 instead of adding 10.

```
import easygui 
import time
from random import *
# Set up Initial Variables
Money = 0
grid = []
character = "X" 
# player_loc will hold the x, y location of the player
player_loc = (0, 0)
# These are a mapping of direction
NORTH = "N"
SOUTH = "S"
EAST  = "E"
WEST  = "W"   #All variables used for Later on
Treasure = "T"
Goblin = "G"


def menu(): #function
   msg = "Would you like to...?" #Users choice to start game
   buttons = ["start", "quit"]
   while True:
      title = "Menu"
      selection = easygui.buttonbox(msg, title , buttons)
      if selection == "quit": 
          exit()
      elif selection ==  "start": #If users input is to start the game the all of this appears("Welcome to the treasure hunt game!")
         easygui.msgbox("These are the rules! You have a choice of a grid ranging from a 3x3 choice to a 20x20 choice")
         easygui.msgbox("In these grids, bandits and treasure chests will spawn at random locations, hidden to you.")
         easygui.msgbox("You will have a choice of the amount of goblins and treasures you would like to spawn in, ranging from 1-2")
         easygui.msgbox("You will move around the map, in search of treasures which will give you 10 gold. Although landing on a goblin would deduct the amount of gold to 0.")
         easygui.msgbox("Furthurmore, just deciding on a position you would like to move to, would give you an extra 1 piece of gold.")
         easygui.msgbox("You can only find the same treasure chest two times before it's replaced by a bandit.")
         easygui.msgbox("To check the amount of gold you have and the amount of bandits and treasure chests in the grid. Simply type 'status'")
         easygui.msgbox("Don't forget! If you have collected all the treasure chests and you don't have 100 gold, you lose the game!")
         easygui.msgbox("Good luck, you will now be entered into the game")
         easygui.msgbox("Ok! let's jump into the game!")
         setupGrid()
         Chests_and_Goblins() 


def setupGrid(): #New function for creating grid
    global grid #Adding/creating global variables
    global row
    global N
    N = easygui.integerbox("How big would you like the grid to be?")                #User input
    while int(N) > 20: #Changing N to an integer so computer understamds
        N = easygui.intergerbox("That number is too high, The grid has to be at a size of under 20x20")
    else:
        while int(N) < 3 : # Asking the user to input again as number is too high or low
        N = easygui.integerbox("That number is too low, the grid has to be a size of over 3x3. Please try again")
       for x in range(0, (int(N))):#For everything in range N
           row = [] #The N amount of rows are created
           for y in range(0, (int(N))): #For everything in range N
               if x == player_loc[0] and y == player_loc[1]: #If the positions is equal to th player location
                   row.append(character) # Add the character in
               else:
                   row.append('O') #Add the same amount of 0's as N
           grid.append(row) 


def Chests_and_Goblins(): #Function used for adding the treasures and goblins in the grid
   global grid
   global row
   global Treasure    
   B = easygui.enterbox(" How many chests would you like in the grid? The amount of chests you like is given by the amount of C's")
   F = easygui.enterbox(" How many Bandits would you like in the grid? The amount of bandits you like is given by the amount of B's")     
   for each in B:
       grid[randint(0, int(N)-1)][randint(0, int(N)-1)] = Treasure
   for each in F:
      grid[randint(0, int(N)-1)][randint(0, int(N)-1)] = Goblin
   gridRunner()   





def moveSouth(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0] + n][player_loc[1]] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0] + n, player_loc[1])
    money()

def moveNorth(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0] - n][player_loc[1]] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0] - n, player_loc[1])
    money()

def moveEast(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1] + n] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0], player_loc[1] + n)
    money()

def moveWest(n):
    global player_loc
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1]] = "O"
    grid[player_loc[0]][player_loc[1] - n] = character
    player_loc = (player_loc[0], player_loc[1] - n)
    money()

def gridRunner():
    while True:
        for row in grid:
            print (row)

        switch = {NORTH : moveNorth,
                  SOUTH : moveSouth,
                  EAST  : moveEast,
                  WEST  : moveWest }
        print (" ")
        P = easygui.enterbox("What direction would you like to move in? North (N), South(S), East(E) or West(W)?")
        if P not in switch:
            easygui.msgbox("invalid move")
            continue
        distance = easygui.integerbox("How far would you like to move in this direction? (blocks are the units)")
        switch[P](distance)

   def money():
   global player_loc
   global character
   global Treasure
   if player_loc == Treasure:
      print("Well done, You have gained coins")
      money = 10
   else:
      print ("You got nothing")
      money = 0


menu()
```

Answer (score 2):

In this part here:

```
  if player_loc == Treasure:
      print("Well done, You have gained coins")
      money = 10
```

You are setting the money to 10, not adding 10. All you need to do is:

```
money += 10
```

Also make sure `def money():` isn't indented; it won't work as it currently is indented.

Comment: Yeah the indentation was an accident although if you run the code you'll see that your edit still does no difference. sorry

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly, you're checking if the (x, y) of the player equals "T" of treasure. double check what you're actually comparing with that line.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to indent the code under your money() function first:

```
   def money():
       global player_loc
       global character
       global Treasure
       if player_loc == Treasure:
          print("Well done, You have gained coins")
          money = 10
       else:
          print ("You got nothing")
          money = 0
```

Comment: The indentation was an accident although even after it's fixed, nothing happens once I land on a treasure chest. Try run the code and you'll see how it odes not work. Thanks though